# How to update Kalman Filter with n-th order state translation?

Tags: continuous-signals, kalman-filters, machine-learning, bayesian-estimation

In Kalman Filter, the hidden state translation is defined by $X_t=F_tX_{t-1}+W_t$, where $X_t$ can be a vector or a single value. This is actually derived from Bayes filter, in which 1-th order markov chain is used with $P(X_t|X_{t-1},...X_1)=P(X_t|X_{t-1})$.

Now, in practice, we actually have that $P(X_t|X_{t-1},...X_1)=P(X_t|X_{t-1},...X_{t-n})$, which is n-th order markov chain, then  how we derive its Kalman Filter with both the prediction and correction step?

I did not find any related documents, and also I did not figure out any tricks to solve my problem based on the standard Kalman Filter (i.e., $X_t=F_tX_{t-1}+W_t$).

Comment: Hi: If that's what's true in your application ( $X_t$ not just being dependent on the previous $X_t$ ), then the process is not markov and you don't have a kalman filter. In your case, it seems  like some kind of autoregressive process might be applicable. But,  if $X_t$ is already a vector, then you would have a vector -vector autoregressive process which I don't think can be transformed to a kalman filter. If $X_t$ is a scalar, it is possible,  you can so look up how to transform a autoregressive model formulation to a KF formulation. if you can't find something, let me and I'll have a look.

Comment: Hi: This doesn't do a great job covering the general case but it has some examples. https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ584/notes/statespacemodels.pdf  . I can't find the paper that explains the general case and I don't have time to look in depth right now. Hopefully the link is enough or you can find something that covers the general case. As I said, if $X_t$ is already a vector, then I don't think reformulation is possible.

Comment: This is a little better but still not what I was looking for. http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/lectures/14_state_space.pdf . Software wise- the dlm package in R does it for you if you're not so interested in the how.

Comment: Are you saying that in *your* practice you have $P(X_t | X_{t-1}, \cdots X_1) = P(X_t | X_{t-1}, \cdots X_n)$, or that that's the case in general?  Because in a Kalman filter, the process is a 1st-order Markov process, and $P_t$ depends only on $P_{t-1}$ and the values of the filter parameters ($F_t$ etc.) at time $t$.

Comment: Hi Tim: I took it as specific to the OP's case.